# Reverse geocode coordinates obtained from Parse

Tags: swift, tableview, reverse-geocoding

This is currently my code

```
let point = object["location"] as! PFGeoPoint
    let location = CLLocation(latitude: point.latitude, longitude:     point.longitude)
    cell.locationButton.text = "\((CLLocation(latitude: currLocation!.latitude, longitude: currLocation!.longitude)))"
```

It returns the coordinates of a specific post and that's fine. What I would like however, is to essentially convert that to the name of the location. I do it for another label however I'm not quite sure how to do it for this specific label, as I'm already inside a cellforrowatindexpath function.

Answer (score 0):

U must implement CLGeocoder if u want to convert coordinates into city names. Check this tutorial out: http://rshankar.com/get-your-current-address-in-swift/

Comment: I know that. I just need to figure out how to do that within a current function.

Comment: u need to update it in func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) .. first fetch the coordinates then query them in that function